# JQUERY SHOW/HIDE for required form fields. Hide if unchecked. Show if check but validation fails

Tags: jquery

I found this script to use in a web form.  When the user clicks a checkbox, then additional required form fields will display. If the checkbox is not clicked, then the hidden form fields are not required.

It works except the problem I am having is this:

1. click the checkbox.
2. required form fields display
3. the user submits the form without filling in the required fields
4. the required form fields are hidden after the page reloads after failing validation, but the checkbox is still checked.

When #4 happens, I would instead like the fields to display after the page reloads because the checkbox is still checked instead of it being hidden.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Hide div w/id extra
       $("#extra").css("display","none");

        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
       $("#delivery").click(function(){

        // If checked
        if ($("#delivery").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra").show("fast");
        }
        else
        {      
            //otherwise, hide it 
            $("#extra").hide("fast");
        }
      });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using jQuery, is it not out of the question to save the reloading of the page by having jQuery validate the form before it is submitted? Seems like a better solution to make sure everything is validated prior to submission, instead of submitting, validating, and bringing back the form to the user.

Comment: There is another circumstance in which I'm encountering this issue besides validation--the fields are hidden when the update version of the form loads.  So I'm really looking for a solution to alter this script which will show the fields when the checkbox has a checkmark. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Hide div w/id extra
$("#extra").hide();

// Toggle content on initial load
extraToggle($("#used_fixed_price_1"), $("#extra"));

// Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id cb
$("#used_fixed_price_1").click(function(){
extraToggle($("#used_fixed_price_1"), $("#extra"));
});
});

function extraToggle(checkbox, extra)
{
// If checked
if(checkbox.is(":checked"))
{
//show the hidden div
extra.show("fast");
}
else
{
//otherwise, hide it
extra.hide("fast");
}
}
```